# How to convert value of type 'ImagePickerView' to expected argument type 'String' on Swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to build an app where a user can insert the name of the movie and can add an image directly into the app from the photo library (using UIKit. Thankfully the part where the user can insert the text and image from the photo library works. My issue is transferring that data from the .sheet to a list. The info in the TextFields that the user inserts works fine and is shown in the list, but the image doesn't show. I keep getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'ImagePickerView' to expected argument type 'String'". I don't know how to fix this issue. This issue comes in the ContentView.swift file, in the MovieRow struct when I try to insert the Image(). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Below is my ContentView file. d

```
//  ContentView.swift
//  MovieListEditttt
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var movieAdd: [MovieAdd] = []

@State private var newMovieName: String = ""
@State private var showNewMovie = false

@State private var newMovieImage = UIImage()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Movies Watched Ratings")
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .black, design: .rounded
                    ))
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.showNewMovie = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                }
            }
            
            List{
                ForEach(movieAdd) {movie in
                    movieRow(movieAdd: movie)
                }
            }
        }
        
        if showNewMovie {
            BlankView(bGColor: .black)
                .opacity(0.5)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showNewMovie = false
                }
            NewMovieView(isShow: $showNewMovie, addMovie: $movieAdd, newMovieName: newMovieName)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 200.0, damping: 25.0, initialVelocity: 10.0))
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}

struct movieRow: View {

@ObservedObject var movieAdd : MovieAdd

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Image(movieAdd.movieImage)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            Text(movieAdd.movieName)
        }
}
}

struct BlankView: View {
var bGColor: Color

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(bGColor)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
}
```

Here is my MovieAdd.swift file where I initialize all variables that will be put inside the list.

```
import Foundation

class MovieAdd: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
@Published var movieName = ""
@Published var isComplete : Bool = false
@Published var movieImage : ImagePickerView

init(movieName: String, isComplete: Bool = false, movieImage: ImagePickerView) {
    self.movieName = movieName
    self.isComplete = isComplete
    self.movieImage = movieImage
}
}
```

And here is my NewMovieView.swift file where the user will be able to insert their Movie information into a TextField, and insert an image from their Photos library. Here is also where I used UIKit.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewMovieView: View {

@Binding var isShow: Bool
@Binding var addMovie: [MovieAdd]

@State var newMovieName: String = ""

@State var isShowingImagePicker = false
@State var imageInBlackBox = UIImage()

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
    VStack {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Add a New Movie")
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                    .bold()
            }
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                HStack (alignment: .center){
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Image(uiImage: imageInBlackBox)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .border(Color.black, width: 3)
                        .clipped()
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isShowingImagePicker.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Select Image")
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker, content: { ImagePickerView(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker, selectedImage: $imageInBlackBox)})
                }
                }
            }
            
            Group {
            TextField("Enter the movie name", text: $newMovieName)
            .padding()
            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                if self.newMovieName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == "" {
                    return
                }
                
                if self.isShowingImagePicker {
                    return 
                }
                
                self.isShow = false
                self.addMovieTask(movieName: self.newMovieName, movieImage: ImagePickerView(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker, selectedImage: $imageInBlackBox))
            }) {
                Text("Save")
                    .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}

private func addMovieTask(movieName: String, isComplete: Bool = false, movieImage: ImagePickerView) {
    
    let task = MovieAdd(movieName: movieName, movieImage: movieImage)
    addMovie.append(task)
}
}

struct NewMovieView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    NewMovieView(isShow: .constant(true), addMovie: .constant([]), newMovieName: "", isShowingImagePicker: true)
}
}

struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Binding var isPresented: Bool
@Binding var selectedImage: UIImage

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerView>) -> some UIViewController {
    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.delegate = context.coordinator
    return controller
}

func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerView.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(parent: self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    let parent: ImagePickerView
    init(parent: ImagePickerView){
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            print(selectedImage)
            self.parent.selectedImage = selectedImage
        }
        self.parent.isPresented = false
    }
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePickerView.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerView>) {
    //
}
}
```

Comment: There's so much code here... It would be really helpful to get it down to a [mre]. What I see right off the bat is that you're trying to make an `Image` with a string description of the image picker (thus your error). Instead, you'll want to use the `selectedImage` from your picker using `Image(uiImage:)`. But, there's just too much code there for me to try to dig through and work out what the actual intent was.

Comment: I appreciate your help. To be more specific, I am trying to get the Image from .sheet to come up on the ContentView file when I try to add It to my MovieAdd array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can pare it down to just the code necessary to reproduce it, I’d be happy to take a look.

Comment: @jnpdx thanks. I managed to trim it down a bunch. A bulk of the NewMovieView.swift file I couldn't trim because of the UIkit code. But the other two files, I managed to trim down a bunch. Also, these are the only three files that I use. Let me know if this helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change #1:**

Your model should *usually* be a `struct` unless there's a really compelling reason to make it an `ObservableObject`. In this case, `struct` works very well:

```
struct MovieAdd: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var movieName = ""
    var isComplete : Bool = false
    var movieImage : UIImage
}
```

*Note that I've made `movieImage` a `UIImage`.*

**Change #2:**

Use `Image(uiImage:)` in `MovieRow`. The `MovieAdd` property no longer needs `@ObservableObject` since it's just a `struct`.

*Also notice that types in Swift should be capitalized to follow convention).*

```
struct MovieRow: View {
    
    var movieAdd : MovieAdd
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Image(uiImage: movieAdd.movieImage)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            Text(movieAdd.movieName)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Complete code in case I forgot to mention any other changes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var movieAdd: [MovieAdd] = []
    
    @State private var newMovieName: String = ""
    @State private var showNewMovie = false
    
    @State private var newMovieImage = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Movies Watched Ratings")
                        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .black, design: .rounded
                        ))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showNewMovie = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }
                }
                
                List{
                    ForEach(movieAdd) {movie in
                        MovieRow(movieAdd: movie)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if showNewMovie {
                BlankView(bGColor: .black)
                    .opacity(0.5)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showNewMovie = false
                    }
                NewMovieView(isShow: $showNewMovie, addMovie: $movieAdd, newMovieName: newMovieName)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 200.0, damping: 25.0, initialVelocity: 10.0))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MovieRow: View {
    
    var movieAdd : MovieAdd
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Image(uiImage: movieAdd.movieImage)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            Text(movieAdd.movieName)
        }
    }
}

struct BlankView: View {
    var bGColor: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(bGColor)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct MovieAdd: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var movieName = ""
    var isComplete : Bool = false
    var movieImage : UIImage
}


struct NewMovieView: View {
    
    @Binding var isShow: Bool
    @Binding var addMovie: [MovieAdd]
    
    @State var newMovieName: String = ""
    
    @State var isShowingImagePicker = false
    @State var imageInBlackBox = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Add a New Movie")
                            .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                            .bold()
                    }
                    ZStack {
                        VStack {
                            HStack (alignment: .center){
                                
                                Spacer()
                                Image(uiImage: imageInBlackBox)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                    .border(Color.black, width: 3)
                                    .clipped()
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.isShowingImagePicker.toggle()
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Select Image")
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                })
                                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker, content: { ImagePickerView(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker, selectedImage: $imageInBlackBox)})
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Group {
                        TextField("Enter the movie name", text: $newMovieName)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                        
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        if self.newMovieName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == "" {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        if self.isShowingImagePicker {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        self.isShow = false
                        self.addMovieTask(movieName: self.newMovieName, movieImage: ImagePickerView(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker, selectedImage: $imageInBlackBox))
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                            .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.white)
        }
    }
    
    private func addMovieTask(movieName: String, isComplete: Bool = false, movieImage: ImagePickerView) {
        
        let task = MovieAdd(movieName: movieName, movieImage: movieImage.selectedImage)
        addMovie.append(task)
    }
}

struct NewMovieView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewMovieView(isShow: .constant(true), addMovie: .constant([]), newMovieName: "", isShowingImagePicker: true)
    }
}

struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerView>) -> some UIViewController {
        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerView.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        let parent: ImagePickerView
        init(parent: ImagePickerView){
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                print(selectedImage)
                self.parent.selectedImage = selectedImage
            }
            self.parent.isPresented = false
        }
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePickerView.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerView>) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @jnpdx , I followed your advice, but in the struct MovieAdd: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var movieName = ""
    var isComplete : Bool = false
    var movieImage : UIImage
}         , for var movieImage: UIImage I get an error saying "Cannot find type 'UIImage' in scope"

Comment: Make sure to `import UIKit`